# Set background color of input in MVC app using C#

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How do I do set the color to Blue? This does not work. IsGuest is a extension method.
I want to set all textboxes on the page in one JQuery statement like this.

```
$(function(){
    $("input").css("background-color", "<%= Html.IsGuest() ? 'blue' : 'white' %>)");
});
```

Thanks
Malcolm

Comment: You have an extra bracket after the 'white' %>)

Comment: Also take a look at generated HTML from the browser.

Answer (score 5):

Try doing this - problem caused by quotation marks

```
$('input').css('background-color', '<%= Html.IsGuest() ? "blue" : "white" %>');
```

Comment: For razor $('input').css('background-color', '@(Html.IsGuest() ? "blue" : "white")');

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("input").css("background-color", <%= Html.IsGuest() ? "'blue'" : "'white'" %>);
```